# Expresión regular para reemplazar classname en documento svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, notepad++

Tengo que cambiar masivamente todos los classname de ficheros exportados de Illustrator, que comparten la misma clase y la intención es añadir un prefijo.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .st1{fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .st2{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;stroke:#A8A8A8;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .st4{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#C166A7;stroke:#A8A8A8;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .st5{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;}
    .st6{fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .st7{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#C77EBB;}
    .st8{opacity:0.55;}
    .st9{fill:#E6F0F0;}
    .st10{fill:#1D70B7;stroke:#F5F5F5;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st11{fill:#BEDCA0;}
    .st12{fill:#D60B51;}
    .st13{fill:#706F6F;}
    .st14{fill:none;stroke:#6F6F6E;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
```

Por ejemplo, reemplazar todos esos (siempre empiezan de 0 y según el tipo de imagen aumenta el número final, y que al final del reemplazo quede así en todo el documento.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .map1-st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .map1-st1{fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .map1-st2{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#F5F0AA;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.01;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .map1-st3{fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .map1-st4{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .map1-st5{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;stroke:#A8A8A8;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .map1-st6{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#FEF58C;}
    .map1-st7{fill:#FEF58C;}
    .map1-st8{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;}
    .map1-st9{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#C77EBB;}
    .map1-st10{fill:#D298C9;}
    .map1-st11{fill:none;}
    .map1-st12{fill:#D298C9;stroke:#1D1D1B;stroke-width:0.01;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .map1-st13{opacity:0.55;}
    .map1-st14{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#D68313;}
    .map1-st15{fill:#E6F0F0;}
    .map1-st16{fill:#706F6F;}
    .map1-st17{fill:none;stroke:#6F6F6E;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses un tester de expresiones regulares online, son bastante utiles cuando debes hacer este tipo de cosas, por ejemplo [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

En cuanto a la expresion regular, en este caso te podria funcionar `\.st[0-9]+`

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
const replaced = text.replace(/\.(st[0-9]+)/g, '.map1-$1');
console.log(replaced)
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .st1{fill:#8FC0D2;}
    .st2{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;stroke:#A8A8A8;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .st3{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .st4{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#C166A7;stroke:#A8A8A8;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
    .st5{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#BEDCA0;}
    .st6{fill:#E8E8E8;}
    .st7{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#C77EBB;}
    .st8{opacity:0.55;}
    .st9{fill:#E6F0F0;}
    .st10{fill:#1D70B7;stroke:#F5F5F5;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st11{fill:#BEDCA0;}
    .st12{fill:#D60B51;}
    .st13{fill:#706F6F;}
    .st143453535{fill:none;stroke:#6F6F6E;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente esa expresión funciona para buscar pero ahora en la línea de reemplazo que tengo que poner para que respete los números y simplemente sea añadir el prefijo?.

Comment: A que te refieres con que respete los numeros? te refieres al 1 de "map1"? debe ser el mismo del final? porque al final los esta conservando.

Comment: Los otros, st0, st1, st2... Ten en cuenta que puede haber en el documento hasta 600 posibles reemplazos. En la busqueda pongo ésto: st[0-9]+ para que busque los class="st9" etc... y necesito que añada el prefijo dejando el resto intacto, es decir, 'map1-st0', 'map1-st3'....etc

Comment: Pero ahi ya lo tienes, cuando escribes `st[0-9]+` estas indicando que busque las cadenas de texto que comiencen con `st` precedidas por 1 o mas digitos. Luego lo unico que debes hacer es reemplazar solo esas porciones  de texto y conservar lo demas, para eso puedes usar el metodo `replace`.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer desde 'Buscar y reemplazar'? Porque la gente que lo necesita hacer no sabe de javascript, y la idea es usar el Search and Replace del Visual Studio Code o Notepad++ etc... Si, me busca el texto tal como dices pero, ponga lo que ponga me reemplaza todo el contenido.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta editada, si el Search & Replace que estas usando soporta las expresiones regulares como javascript, simplemente debes agrupar lo que quieres conservar entre parentesis dentro de la expresion regular: `\.(st[0-9]+)` => `.map1-$1`; este seria el reemplazo, `$1` le indica que conserve lo que esta entre parentesis y le agregue '.map1-'. Si te fue de utilidad mi respuesta recuerda marcarla como la respuesta aceptada ;)

Comment: Fantástico, ahora si que si jeje. Muchas gracias.